# What's the best way to design a DynamoDB table to store cloudwatch alarms

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Actually i'm using Cloudwatch to generate alarms for my different services (Elasticsearch, RDS, ELB, ...) and my goal is to store these alarms in a DynamoDB table.

These are the fieds that i will store :

```
 - Service (Elasticsearch, RDS, ELB, ...)
 - Priority of the alert(P1,P2,P3,P4)
 - Datetime
 - Resource Name
 - Status
 - Reason
```

Is it ok to design the table like that :

```
id = Service#Priority
sort_key = Datetime
```

Or simply :

```
id = Service
sort_key = Datetime
```

I'm not sure what's the best approach to use to better design the table.

NOTE : About 50 alerts will be stored each day.

Thanks.

Comment: What are your Get/Query Scenario? With which key can a scan be avoided? Do you have some Hot Partitions? Why you are using DynamoDB?

Comment: An example of query would be to get Priority 1 Alerts for Service Elasticsearch for a date range. What do you mean by "which key can a scan be avoided" ?

Comment: It is possible to read Items from DynamoDB with Get (Exact Partion and Sort Key), Query (Exact Partion and conditional sort key) or Scan (All Partitions and any sort key). You should avoid to scaning the table.

Comment: @Matthias Yes, but what's the best way to design the table to optimize the queries and not to use Scan

Answer (score 0):

Is this 50 alerts per service/resource combination or 50 overall? Why not schedule an export from AWS Cloudwatch and have your analytics built on the S3/Athena combination.

You should also consider using AWS EMR for such log analytics use cases. Any reason why you are building your solution on DynamoDB, as any of the above partition techniques may tend to create hot spots which will be performance dampener.

Comment: It will be about 50 overall alerts. I'm using Cloudwatch Alarm, i don't find how to export them to S3 ?? Actually they are redirected to SNS which trigger a Lambda that sends an Email.

I thought that it will be easy to write them directly (using the same Lambda) to a table, that's why i think to use DynamoDB